# python import class from another folder's file

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I'm using python 3 and My folder structure is as below

```
Main_Folder
> Export
> >exportmanager.py

> Examples
>  >test.py
```

exportmanager.py file has a class ExportManager which I need to import in test.py.
so far I have tried

```
from Export.exportmanager import ExportManager
from Main_Folder.Export import exportmanager.py then from exportmanager.py import ExportManager
```

and some other.
But I keep getting no module found.

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder

Answer (score 0):

The only quick, dirty solution that came to my mind is having this structure:

```
.
├── Examples
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test.py
├── Main_Folder
│   ├── Export
│   │   └── exportmanager.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
```

And suppose your **exportmanager.py** looks like this:

```py
def fun():
    print("This is from Export Manager!")
```

And then you import this in your **test.py** using:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
from Main_Folder.Export import exportmanager


exportmanager.fun()
```

I tried using relative imports, other "simplest" solutions, all of them gave the same error **"ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"**.
So if you're looking for a dirty workaround, this might be it. As to why there are a few ****init**.py** files, which are basically empty in this case, I encourage you to read about it more (i.e. [here](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/))

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your you exportmanager.py looks like this:

```
def fun():
    print("This is from Export Manager!")
```

You can write this code in your test.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
from sys import path
path.append(str(Path(__file__).parents[1] /Path('Main/Export')))

import exportmanger

exportmanger.fun()
```

I try to using answer by Przemysław Samsel, but it makes a ModuleNotFoundError!

Comment: That's another take I guess, I don't really get what's the division "/" doing there. What my code does it's just appending parent directory to Python's path. Then, if you've created all those __init__.py files as I've pointed out, Python should have not problem finding the exportmanager. Anyway, let's see what OP says

Comment: The "/" was moving through the directory tree. I answer was appending Main_Folder/Export directory to Python's path